# how to invoke javascript from Internet Explorer DOM

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, excel, vba

I'm using VBA (Excel) to manipulate a dropdown box in web page loaded in Internet Explorer. The dropdown box has some javascript attached so that the page's UI controls will change when the dropdown selection is changed.

I use the below function to (automatically) select an option from the dropdown. It changes the value of the dropbox *but it does not trigger the UI changes* (as compared to when I manually change the dropdown box).

```
Sub selectFromDropdown(ByRef dropdown As HTMLSelectElement, ByVal optionName As String)
    Dim opts
    Dim opt As HTMLOptionElement

    dropdown.Focus
    dropdown.setCapture
    Set opts = dropdown.children
    For i = 1 To opts.Length
        Set opt = opts.Item(i)
        If opt.Text = optionName Then
            opt.Selected = True
            dropdown.selectedIndex = opt.Index
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    dropdown.releaseCapture
End Sub
```

So how can I trigger the javascript that is attached to this dropdown box? Or in general, how can I fire an event programmatically via the API provided by MS Internet Explorer? Thank you.

Comment: Very funny but isn't that the force behind all those automated web testing tool! Are you aware of them?

Comment: @Martin08, VBA+IE+JavaScript sounds like masochism to me. Any *one* of those items alone might be fine; combining all three is the sort of thing I have nightmares about.

Answer (score 1):

You should show enough HTML that we can see the javascript attached and the type of event.

Lets say it is an "onclick"

You could have

```
opt.Selected = True
opt.FireEvent "onclick"
```

Answer (score 0):

call your javascript function explicitly when you set combobox value.

```
Sub selectFromDropdown(ByRef dropdown As HTMLSelectElement, ByVal optionName As String)
    Dim opts
    Dim opt As HTMLOptionElement

    dropdown.Focus
    dropdown.setCapture
    Set opts = dropdown.children
    For i = 1 To opts.Length
        Set opt = opts.Item(i)
        If opt.Text = optionName Then
            opt.Selected = True
            dropdown.selectedIndex = opt.Index
            'Call hear javascript function.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    dropdown.releaseCapture
End Sub
```